# column (in index format) to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a column in my dataframe that is formatted like an index:

```
0      [u'Basketball', u'Swimming', u'Gym']
1      [u'Gym', u'Soccer', u'Football']
2      [u'Ballet', u'Basketball', u'Volleyball']
```

Is there an easy way for me to clean this up (remove the u, and the square brackets) then  split them by (',') such that sports are grouped to three columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider `s`

```
s = pd.Series([
      "[u'Basketball', 'Swimming', 'Gym']",
      "[u'Gym', u'Soccer', u'Football']",
      "[u'Ballet', u'Basketball', u'Volleyball']"
    ])
s

0           [u'Basketball', 'Swimming', 'Gym']
1             [u'Gym', u'Soccer', u'Football']
2    [u'Ballet', u'Basketball', u'Volleyball']
dtype: object
```

quickest way is to `apply` `eval`

```
s.apply(eval)

0         [Basketball, Swimming, Gym]
1             [Gym, Soccer, Football]
2    [Ballet, Basketball, Volleyball]
dtype: object
```

to get a dataframe

```
s.apply(eval).apply(pd.Series)
```

[image]